# Is it possible to download and replace an xml file from an AIR app (ActionScript 3)?

Tags: android, ios, xml, actionscript-3, air

I've got an AIR app (AS3) that displays information from a local xml file.

I'd like to know if it's possible to make the code check the version of the xml file on the internet and see if there is a more recent one on my server. If so, the app would download and replace the xml file.

This way I won't have to update the all app just for updating the xml file infos.

And, do you know if IOS (or Android) can allows the app to download and replace the xml without the knowledge of the user ?

I was thinking something like this but I've never tried to make a file to be downloaded and replace the original one on AS3 :

```
if(myXMLfile.name == data.name_of_xml_Online){
//do nothing
else{
startDownload();
}

function startDownload():void 
    { 
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(); 
        request.url = http://www.mywebsite/xmlfile.xml; 
        fr.download(request); 
}
```

EDIT

Here's what I did :

```
function startDownload():void{
var urlString:String = "http://mywebsite/horaires3.xml";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
urlStream.load(urlReq);



function loaded(event:Event):void {
urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
writeFile();
}



function writeFile():void {
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("horaires3.xml");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream()
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    urlRemote_txt.text = file.url;
fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
fileStream.close();
trace("The AIR file is written.");
}

}
```

The file is downloaded, no errors, but it doesn't seems to replace the horaires3.xml of the app..

```
urlRemote_txt.text = app-storage:/horaires3.xml
```

and before I've enter `urlLocal_txt.text` for the local xml file and it was `= horaires3.xml`

So it seems there is 2 differents "directory" or is it because I'm testing it on a computer instead of the device ?

Note that for the original horaires3.xml, it's included in my project via the publish settings in Adobe Animate.

[image: screen capture of the original xml]

Maybe, I have to find a way to move my original horaires3.xml file to app-storage:/ location...?

If anyone have an idea on this matter.

Comment: You cannot replace the original file because **app:/** location is read-only. However, you have full access to **app-storage:/** (*note: one slash is correct*) location, I think you don't even need any permissions to write things to it. You can use **File** + **FileStream** classes to write a file to the storage folder.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So, if I want to update the xml file of the app, what do you suggest I do ?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. You are unable to devise a suitable algorithm? You don't know how to translate it to AS3?

Comment: Calm down dude. This is a forum for help. If I knew what to do, do you really think I would take the time to make a post ? Obviously I don't know what logic to use. So, if you can help, good. If not, no need to post something.

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, [not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum).  As for calming down, consider that you're lecturing someone that you're asking to volunteer to help you for free. 

@steph45

Comment: As for suggestions, sorry, it's hard to know what to suggest without knowing anything about the application.  Maybe just load the data from the server every time?

Answer (score 0):

[`FileReference.download()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download()) seems to prompt the user, so I'm guessing you don't want that. And I don't know if [`File.copyTo()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#copyTo()) will work for a remote file like that. If it doesn't, you could try using [`FileStream`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) like this:

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

var remoteFile:FileStream = new FileStream();
remoteFile.open(pathToRemoteFile, FileMode.READ);
remoteFile.readBytes(byteArray);
remoteFile.close();

var localFile:FileStream = new FileStream();
localFile.open(pathToLocalFile, FileMode.WRITE);
localFile.writeBytes(byteArray);
localFile.close();
```

Comment: Maybe, I have to find a way to move my original horaires3.xml file to app-storage:/ location...?

Comment: You wrote `urlRemote_txt.text = app-storage:/horaires3.xml`. Doesn't that mean your file is already in app-storage?

Comment: It seems there is a difference between `app-storage:/horaires3.xml` and `horaires3.xml` as my xml file `horaires3.xml` isn't replaced by `app-storage:/horaires3.xml`